# How to make a square object disappear with mouse cursor on top of it when square was made from Math.random()

Tags: javascript, html, mouseevent, mouseover

I want to make squares I made with the Math.random() function disappear when my mouse moves over them. I tried many ways but can't seem to get it right.

I just want a square to be removed if the cursor goes on it
This is my code I have so far:

```
    function draw(){  
      var dom = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
      if (dom.getContext) {
          var ctx = dom.getContext('2d');
          var width  = window.innerWidth;
          var height = window.innerHeight;

          dom.width=width; // assign width to canvas
          dom.height=height; //assign height to canvas

          //use so squares aren't cut off 
          positionW=window.innerWidth - 110;
          positionH=window.innerHeight - 110;

        function makeSquares(n){
          for(let i = 0; i < n; i++){

            var x = Math.random()* positionW; 
            var y = Math.random()* positionH;

            //make squares colourful
            ctx.globalAlpha=0.5; //opacity
            var color = '#'+ Math.round(0xffffff * Math.random()).toString(16);
            ctx.fillStyle = color;

            //draw rectangle
            ctx.fillRect(x,y,100,100);
          }
        }
      //initialize 
        makeSquares(100);

        }
      }

      draw();
```

Comment: onmouseenter and onmouseleave

Comment: If you are looking to target each individual square you have created inside the canvas, these will not be able to be targeted by the DOM as they are not in the document object model, you will only be able to target the individual canvas as a whole.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add class to canvas element HTML5 & CreateJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27943403/add-class-to-canvas-element-html5-createjs)